# powershell get specific row from a body

Tags: powershell

i'm getting some problem to get a specific row from a powershell body. HR team send email to us, a logic app get the body of email and pass it to a script that disable the user.

The body is like this:

```
Hi,

the following user have to be dismiss:

#mail: user1@mycompany.com
#mail: user2@mycompany.com
#mail: user2@mycompany.com


Bye
hr team

hrteam@mycompany.com
```

i would like to get only the specific row:

```
    #mail: user1@mycompany.com
    #mail: user2@mycompany.com
    #mail: user2@mycompany.com
```

to do this i did a trick with following code:

```
    $Body
    $SplitBody = $Body.split("").split(" ").Split("#")
    $objetbody = $SplitBody.Replace(" ","").Trim()
```

and i got following result:

```
Hi,
the
following
user
have
to
be
dismiss:

mail:
user1@mycompany.com

mail:
user2@mycompany.com

mail:
user2@mycompany.com
Bye
hr
team
hrteam@mycompany.com
```

after that i pass $objetbody into a foreach and loop all row(at the end of this foreach is put a break becouse it can disable HR mail). The flow work if HR sent only 1 mail to disable.

My question is there is a way to got that specific row that contains the mails?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a one-liner to output all email addresses using the .NET [RegEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-6.0) class:

```
[RegEx]::Matches( $body, '(?<=#mail:\s*)\S+' ).Value
```

The same can be achieved using [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.2):

```
($body | Select-String '(?<=#mail:\s*)\S+' -AllMatches).Matches.Value
```

**RegEx breakdown:**

- `(?<=` ... starts a positive look behind pattern, meaning that the sub string we search for must be preceded by the given pattern, but this pattern won't be included in the result

  - `#mail:\s*` ... literal "#mail:" followed by optional whitespace
- `)` ... ends the look behind pattern
- `\S+` ... any sequence of non-whitespace characters -> the email address

I kept the email address pattern simple, because correctly [matching email addresses using RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) can be hard. Anyway you propably want to do validation as a separate step so you can report invalid addresses. This can be done much simpler using the .NET [`MailAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) class:

```
$mailAddresses = [RegEx]::Matches( $body, '(?<=#mail:\s*)\S+' ).Value

foreach( $adr in $mailAddresses) {
    try {
        [System.Net.Mail.MailAddress]::new( $adr )
    } catch {
        # The MailAddress constructor throws FormatException for invalid address
        Write-Error "Invalid mail address: '$adr'"
    }    
}
```

Comment: Hi Zett your code works fine. Really appreciate it!!!!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You could use a loop in addition to the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators) operator and the use of the [automatic variable `$Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#matches):

```
foreach($line in $Body)
{
    if($line -match '^#mail: (.*@.*\.[\w\d]+)')
    {
        $Matches[1]
    }
}
```

From the example above, `$Matches[1]` would return the values for the matched capturing group:

```
user1@mycompany.com
user2@mycompany.com
user2@mycompany.com
```

If you want to keep `#mail:`  use `$Matches[0]` instead.

Comment: Hi santiago, i tried your code but i got this with $matches[0]:
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                        
0                              @mycompany.com
$matches[1] is empty i see. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks!!